# EF Core 2.2.2 - Update database failing, MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I currently have EF Core 2.2.2 setup and running in my .NET Core Web API project. I am using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`as my MySQL provider for EF Core. I am able to successfully create a new migration for my database but as soon as I run `Update-Database` I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445486', 'Concentrates', '2019-02-23
>   14:44:41.445486');

Which is strange since I have been using this migration for a couple of weeks now and run `Update-Database` quite frequently as I drop the database during my development and then re-create it. I have the following code to generate my data that is being seeded that is causing the error:

```
//Seed categories
string[] categories = { "Concentrates", "Food", "Specials & combos", "Clones", "Seeds" };
var catCount = 1;

foreach (var category in categories)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(new Category
    {
        Id = catCount,
        Name = category,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now
    });

    catCount++;
}
```

The above is being run in the following method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

The model for my categories is defined as follows:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataAccessLayer.Database.Store
{
    public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the `BaseEntity` defined as the following:

```
using System;

namespace DataAccessLayer.Database
{
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, that the generated code that I find in the console I am able to execute in my database tool successfully without error. It generates the following SQL code in the console that I am able to see and execute manually without error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (277ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `CreatedAt`, `Name`, `UpdatedAt`)
VALUES (1, '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445486', 'Concentrates', '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445486');
INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `CreatedAt`, `Name`, `UpdatedAt`)
VALUES (2, '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445485', 'Food', '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445485');
INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `CreatedAt`, `Name`, `UpdatedAt`)
VALUES (3, '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445484', 'Specials & combos', '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445484');
INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `CreatedAt`, `Name`, `UpdatedAt`)
VALUES (4, '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445483', 'Clones', '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445483');
INSERT INTO `Categories` (`Id`, `CreatedAt`, `Name`, `UpdatedAt`)
VALUES (5, '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445467', 'Seeds', '2019-02-23 14:44:41.445468');
```

Here is the CREATE statement for the `Categories` table that is giving the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CreatedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Does anyone possibly have an idea why I am getting the error when I try to run `Update-Database` but am able to successfully manually execute the SQL?

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is your problem but why are you setting an `Id` if you are using the datbasegenerated option? I'm not experienced with MySQL but I would expect that to fail unless you have done the MySQL equivalent of IDENTITY INSERT ON

Comment: It required it, all the hasData methods required me to explicitly define the Id's even though it is set to database generated, I am not quite sure why though.

Comment: have you try the select statement? is it working? because if you have any error it should return an error not timeout. i am afraid if there is any issue in connection string.

Comment: Can you check if your table datatype is correctly set as `DATETIME(6)` by the command which is required to store `2019-02-23 14:44:41.445486`?  You can do that with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: @RaymondNijland - The datatypes for both `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are `DATETIME(6)`. So it is unfortunately not that.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and generated SQL? Or is there no way to get the generated SQL in that framework?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I've added the table structure, the `INSERT` that is being generated is posted above.

Comment: Ok i have no idea, the table structure and insert statements are perfect [valid](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f29RukVFyVGF7woCGFE1Rw/0) offcource .. But i find it wierd that the application is setting the id column instead off leting the database handle it..

Comment: Like it just said it's wierd seeing `AUTO_INCREMENT=15`in the create table statement and application generated id's  which are lower in the `1 - 5` range really does not make sense also.. But that would not explain the parse error..

Comment: Yea I must say I am pretty stumped to why this is happening.