# Can't do bulk INSERT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am currently using [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/) to access my databases. Over the past few days I have dropped and re-created my database using Entity Framework Core without problem. I started experiencing issues yesterday which is outlined in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841874/ef-core-2-2-2-update-database-failing-mysql).

Today I spun up three Amazon AWS RDS instances, one MySQL 8.0.13, one MySQL 5.7 and one MariaDB 10.3.8. I then connected my Entity Framework Core project to each of these instances and created my database. After that I tried to execute my `.sql` file to `INSERT` the data into the table. It fails for all three, however - if I copy the data out of the `.sql` file and copy it into a query window I am able to execute the exact same SQL script one by one without issue, so there is no problem with the data.

The error message I am getting from all three is as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL/MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Here is a snippet of the data I am trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (1, 'Afpak', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.237187', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.237187');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (2, 'African', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.639772', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.639772');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (3, 'Afternoon Delight', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.969709', '2019-02-09 18:29:35.969709');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (4, 'Afwreck', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.303370', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.303370');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (5, 'Agent Orange', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.633222', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.633222');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (6, 'Agent Tangie', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.970400', '2019-02-09 18:29:36.970400');
INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (8, 'Alaska', '2019-02-09 18:29:37.305867', '2019-02-09 18:29:37.305867');
```

Here is the create script of the table itself:

```
CREATE TABLE `Names` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2162 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I've tried changing the character sets of the database and the tables with no success. I honestly have no idea what else to try, does anyone possibly have an idea to what it could be?

Comment: IS it possible that is no Database selected when you execute it from a file. Try to add first **USE YOURDATABASE;** in the file

Comment: @BerndBuffen - unfortunately not making a difference.

Comment: @Tachyon Please [edit] your question to include the statements how you try to load the SQL file. Also include the complete error message you get to the question. Btw.: you should add the columns in your `INSERT INTO` statement and not rely blindly on the order of the columns.

Comment: The rest of the error message has the meat; show it to us.